# Scrapy Python - How to Pass URL and retrieve URL for Scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I have very little programming experience with python more with Java.

I am trying to get into python and having problems with understanding a scrapy web crawler I am trying to setup.

The script will scrape products etc from the site and put them into a file and recursively go through all landing domains within the site but stop at a specified depth.

I'm having trouble understanding how I can pass a URL exectued within a script to an example of scrapy I found.

Code that executes my spider:

## Scrappy Code is here --------------------------------

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(UrlScrappyRunner, domain="www.google.com")
process.start()
```

My Spider:

```
class UrlScrappyRunner(scrapy.Spider):

        name = "quotes"

        def start_requests(self):
            urls = [
                'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
                'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
            ]
            for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

        def parse(self, response):
            page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
            filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)
            self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Please can you let me know how to pass the domain=www.google.com to my spider so it crawls google rather than quotes.toscrape.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use argumets `-a` in scrapy to pass the user defined values

```
class UrlScrappyRunner(scrapy.Spider):
            name = "quotes"

           def __init__(self, domain=None, *args, **kwargs):
                self.domain = domain

            def start_requests(self):
                urls = self.domain
```

to run with argument

```
scrapy crawl UrlScrappyRunner -a domain="www.google.com"
```

to run from process:

```
process.crawl(UrlScrappyRunner, domain="www.google.com")
```

add `__init__` in your code and assign the domain value in you class variable

Comment: thanks for this. But the problem is I am running it within a script rather than on command line, so using this process.crawl(UrlScrappyRunner, domain="www.google.com")

Comment: @Raj, Everything is same only. take a look at the updated answer. you can pass like this process.crawl(UrlScrappyRunner, domain="www.google.com")

Comment: @Raj, One thing you have to do it, __init__ nothing but a constructor. In which you have to get the arguments and assign to your variables

Answer (score 0):

This is how to pass urls as arguments to a CrawlerProcess spider on Scrapy 1.4.0:

**main.py**

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from myspider import MySpider

if __name__ == '__main__':
  process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'FEED_URI': destination_file_uri  # URI to destination file
  })
  process.crawl(MySpider, myurls=[
    'http://example.com'
  ])
```

Where destination_file_uri is something like "file:///path/to/results.json".

**myspider.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.myurls = kwargs.get('myurls', [])
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.myurls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        """ Test: extract quotes """
        for quote in response.xpath('//blockquote').extract():
            yield {"quote": quote}
```

Where *myurls* is a not already used property name (you can change it).